# get value from datagrid cell in C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

How do I get the info from a certain cell in a data grid?  I want an event to happen when a person clicks the button in the 7th column, but the event depends on the value in the first column.  here's what i have, but nothing is happening.

```
if (InventoryDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 7)
            {

                if(InventoryDataGridView[0,0].Equals("Books"))
                {
                    Books open = new Books();
                    open.Show();
                }

        }
```

Nothing happens though

Comment: Are you using WPF or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InventoryDataGridView[0,0]
```

only refers to the DataGridViewCell. That class has a Value property which contains the value of the cell.

so that line should look like this:

```
if(InventoryDataGridView[0,0].Value.Equals("Books"))
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you using WPF then you must try this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGrid1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    string s=(dataGrid1.Items[i] as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[j].ToString();
                }
            }
```

i,j are the co-ordinates. So you can play around it.

reference: http://subrat308.blogspot.in/2012/02/wpf-get-cell-value-from-datagrid-cellij.html

Comment: InventoryDataGridView so i think this is WinForm

Comment: himm.. ok then. )) But anyway the link i posted in my answer was very helpful for me while using WPF DataGrid agter googling about 1 day.